Can someone translate this odd Latin text from an Italian church
I received a copy of the following text from a church in Italy.  It appears to be Latin but not any form that is easily translated.  Could it possibly be a local dialect?
The church is located here.  The inscription may be on the small chapel but the dates don't seem to match.  Here's a wikipedia article about the town.  If I can get a hold of a picture of the original inscription I'll post it.



It is not so much a local dialect as an imperfect transcript of the original inscription. Some parts are perfectly legible, e.g. … sacellum hoc edificandum curavit anno … Others are more difficult.

(I'm obviously personally intrigued by this question )

I'd love to know what church this came from. The transcript looks surprisingly (to me) modern in terms of handwriting. I'd trust a photo a lot more than I do this.

If you can [edit] any more details into your question, that would be very helpful. Do you have a photo of the text? What is the name of the church? Which city is it in? You will get far better answers if you can supply more detail; the current level is not quite enough for a reliable interpretation.

@SebastianKoppehel I've added more information.  But I don't have a picture yet.

Thank you very much! "Oratorio di San Bartolomeo, situato nella stessa piazza della chiesa, si tratta di una piccola cappella privata costruita nel 1725 dalla famiglia Coppelli." Ha ha, so much for all the Middle Ages speculation :D

@SebastianKoppehel. I've been able to get an image of the actual inscription.  I added it to the original post. Hopefully this helps.

(This is a partial answer--in almost all other details I agree with Ilya's answer)
I think the crucial middle line should be transcribed as follows:

Ut magnus hic novus honor exhiberetur

This makes sense of the contracted "HNR" (not "HNS") as well as the contracted "EXBRT" (not "EXSRT"). In addition, this has a much more probable meaning where "ut" is a purpose clause and "cui" goes with "exhiberetur":

. . . to whom [i.e. to St. Bartholomew], in order that this great new honor might be conferred . . .

The imperfect subjunctive is the expected tense for a purpose clause in secondary sequence. In addition, exhibere honorem alicui is attested in Cicero and explicitly mentioned as a late-Latin idiom by L&S, I.B.1.β.

I agree with Brian. I also wonder about NOE: normally that's nomine.

UPDATED ANSWER (with access to photograph)
It is ecclesiastical Latin written by a person who spoke it, but did not read or write it. It appears to be a re-inscription of a more ancient writing. In other words, what may have happened is that the original chapel had this inscription possibly in paint, but when the chapel was renovated, the inscription was redone in stone.
My reading has not changed much seeing the photograph, except for the two QUI's. Also, given the "qui" I would read CERN as cernuo or cernuiis which refers (in eccelsiastical contexts) to prostrate worshipping. I would read divus substantively.
It is probably meant to be read as follows:

In caelo magnus : cern[uo or cernuis]
qui divus hic recolitur
superna luce induitur
qui pelle nudus tollitur
    --- cui ---
ut magnus hic novus HNR•EXBRT (INRI Χρ[ιστοσ] r[egula]t)
D[ixit]: Alexander Coppellius
nec no[ll]e : nec piate : secu[n]dus
   --- sacellum hoc ---
aedificandum curavit
an[n]o repetens n[ost]re
       1728

The intent seems to be the following:
In heaven the great divinity [of God] is here worshipped prostrate once more, bathed in celestial light.
By whose strength [my] naked body is empowered in order that Jesus Christ of Nazareth, King of the Jews, may rule in new greatness. Alexander Coppellius spoke: lacking neither in duty or piety, I took care of the erection of this chapel, restoring it in the year of our Lord 1728.
Note that curavit is in third person, so literally it says "his naked body ... he took care of ... he spoke" but the meaning is such that in English we would express the same thing in the first person, ie: "I am raised up .. I took care of ... I spoke this ..."
To understand the general purpose of this inscription the word recolit[u]r is critical. This word means "is worshipped again" so basically what it means is that this structure had fallen into ruin and the author has restored it (repetens) so that Christ may be worshipped again at this chapel.
I read HRN*EXBRT as shown. I originally considered the other respondent's idea of EXSTITERIT, but it seemed less likely to me because, among other things INRI is unlikely to stand alone without CHRISTOS, so /E/XB more likely must be a corruption for Xp (Chi Rho) meaning Christos. Seeing the photo has not changed this opinion. In fact, it is hard to read the photo as EXST because the supposed "S" does not look like the other S's in the inscription. It is clearly a "B" not an "S".
Note that in this last interpretation we see evidence that it is a purely verbal utterance, not literal, because the speaker probably said "Ex Peh" (meaning actually "ex rho", intending XP) and the stone cutter misheard him and wrote instead "EXB". So, the stone cutter is mishearing a "beh" for a "peh". Such a mistake would never have occurred if there had not been an oral communication.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
